# expo credentials:manager is not supported in the local CLI

Tags: react-native, expo

Upon typing the command "expo credentials:manager -p android" in terminal, I get:

'expo credentials:manager is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas credentials instead'

However, I know i recently uninstalled EAS so I cannot use eas credentials.

Is there any way to still use expo credentials:manager -p android? Also, why is it not supported?

Comment: did you figure this one out yet? running into same issue when trying to run an Android expo project (that uses Google Oauth config in expo-session).